# Usage of that with additional information about the subject

Tags: conjunctions, clauses, subordinate-clauses

My objective is to combine following two sentences:

A.  I assume you have access to the books that you were mentioning.

B.  I assume you have those books in digital format.

Possibility 1: I assume you have access to the books (in digital format) that you were mentioning.
I thought of removing double brackets but I think “that” should immediately follow “books”.

Possibility 2:  I assume you have access to the books that you were mentioning in digital format. This also doesn't look good.

I think in this case there is an additional information about books - that they are in digital format.

Is there a suitable way to combine both of the above sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say, I assume, ***you have the books*** or ***you have access to those books*** is not very different.

So, "I assume that you have in digital format those books you were  mentioning about"  or  "I assume that you have access in digital format to those books you were mentioning about" will do.

Answer (score 1):

Is my solution too simple?

> I assume you have access to the digital books you were mentioning.

(Sorry, I left out the *that* you were mentioning in your headline, but the sentence anyway works with and without it quite similarly.)

Comment: I think this is a very clear and correct way of communicating the information. +1 from me.

Comment: I like your simple answer. +1 from me as well. It seems my reputation is below 15 and should reflect later.